There is no registered service of type 'Blazorise.Localization.ITextLocalizerService'
My script is trying to display images within Blazorise Carousel component. No error during compilation, no error on image path, but when loading the page, i get this error below. I search around online, but cannot find anything related this this error.
Error message: "InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'LocalizerService' on type 'Blazorise.Carousel'. There is no registered service of type 'Blazorise.Localization.ITextLocalizerService'."
Error is happening to this section below.
<Carousel Interval="5000">
            @foreach (var imagePath in imagePaths)
            {
                <CarouselSlide>
                    <img src="@($"images/{imagePath}")" class="d-block w-100" alt="Slide">
                </CarouselSlide>
            }
        </Carousel>

Full code below.
<!-- Index.razor -->
@page "/"
@using System.IO
@using Blazorise
@using Blazorise.Localization

<h1>Image List</h1>

@if (imagePaths != null && imagePaths.Any())
{
    <div class="image-list">
        @* @foreach (var imagePath in imagePaths)
        {
            <img src="@GetRelativePath(imagePath)" alt="Image">

        } *@

        <Carousel Interval="5000">
            @foreach (var imagePath in imagePaths)
            {
                <CarouselSlide>
                    <img src="@($"images/{imagePath}")" class="d-block w-100" alt="Slide">
                </CarouselSlide>
            }
        </Carousel>


    </div>
}
else
{
    <p>No images found.</p>
}

@code {
    private List<string> imagePaths;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var folderPath = "wwwroot/images"; // Path to your images folder
        imagePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.jpg")
                               .Concat(Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.png"))
                               .ToList();
    }

    private string GetRelativePath(string absolutePath)
    {
        return absolutePath.Replace("wwwroot", string.Empty);
    }
}



You could try install Blazorise.Bootstrap and register like following in both server project and client projet(if you have).
builder.Services
    .AddBlazorise()
    .AddBootstrapProviders();

